# c# Caesar cipher alphabet enum to strings

Tags: c#, encryption, enums

I am making a console application which encrypt messages in the style ceasar increased 5 letters , but I can only encrypt messages 1 letter of 2 or more can not I get error
I want to encrypt a sentence of more than 2 letters, as I do?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Cesar
{
    enum letras { a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, ñ, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z, A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, Ñ, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X, Y, Z, };
class Cesar 
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int op = 0, res;
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Cifrar un mensaje [1]\n" + "Descifrar un mensaje [2]\n" + "Sair [3]\n");
            res = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            op = res;
            Cesar cift = new Cesar();
            if (res == 1)
            {
                Cesar.cifrar();
            }
            if (res == 2)
            {
                Cesar.descifrar();
            }
            if (res == 3)
            {
                Console.In.Close();
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Escribe un numero del 1 al 3");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
    public static void cifrar()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Escribe el mensaje");
        string letra = Console.ReadLine();
        letras l = (letras)Enum.Parse(typeof(letras), letra);
        Console.WriteLine("Cifrado: " + (l + 5));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    public static void descifrar()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Escribe el cifrado");
        string letra = Console.ReadLine(); ;

        letras l = (letras)Enum.Parse(typeof(letras), letra);
        Console.WriteLine("Descifrado: " + (l - 5));
        Console.ReadLine();
    } 

}
```

Comment: You need to loop over each character of the string `letra` in both `cifrar()` and `descifrar()`.  [This link might give you a hint](http://www.dotnetperls.com/loop-chars).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are likely going outside the bounds of your defined enum. You need to create a circular addition.

```
public static void cifrar()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Escribe el mensaje");
    string letra = Console.ReadLine();
    letras l = (letras)Enum.Parse(typeof(letras), letra);
    Console.WriteLine("Cifrado: " + ((l + 5) % 53)); //Use the modulus operator to prevent going beyond the end of the enum
    Console.ReadLine();
}

public static void descifrar()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Escribe el cifrado");
    string letra = Console.ReadLine(); ;

    letras l = (letras)Enum.Parse(typeof(letras), letra);
    int di = ((int)l) - 5; //Move back 5 letters
    if(di < 0) di = 53 + di; //We moved to a negative number, circle back to the end

    Console.WriteLine("Descifrado: " + ((letras)di));
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Thanks but still does not work with %53 error mark me and console me int di prints numbers ( 56,58,59 )

Comment: if(di < 0) di = 53 - di; This is your problem. di is negative, so you'd want to use 53 + di OR 53 - (di*-1) - OR you could use 53 - Math.Abs(di) :) hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
        public static void cifrar()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Escribe el mensaje");
        string letra = Console.ReadLine();

        letras l = (letras)Enum.Parse(typeof(letras), letra);
        int di = ((int)l) + 5;
        if (di > 53) di = ((int)l) - 49; 

        Console.WriteLine("Cifrado: " + ((letras)di));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    public static void descifrar()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Escribe el cifrado");
        string letra = Console.ReadLine(); ;

        letras l = (letras)Enum.Parse(typeof(letras), letra);
        int di = ((int)l) - 5; 
        if (di < 0) di = ((int)l) + 49; 

        Console.WriteLine("Descifrado: " + ((letras)di));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: even words can not encrypt more than one letter